# Running capistrano v2 and v3 on different apps on the same machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I just made a new rails app running on capistrano v3 and everything is fine.

Then I tried to deploy an old app running on capistrano v2 and capistrano doesn't work and can't load:

`cap aborted!
cannot load such file -- deploy
blabla/Capfile:1:in`load'
blabla/Capfile:1:in `<top (required)>'`

running `bundle show capistrano` returns capistrano v2 but running `which gem capistrano` returns capistrano v3.

How can i keep it running the old capistrano v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try prefixing with `bundle exec`, i.e.

```
bundle exec cap deploy
```